# find files older than create its parent folder in a directory and move them there

Tags: bash, unix, terminal, shell, bash-scripting

I've been trying to create a bash script that does the following.

Use the `find` command to search for files older than 7 days (`find . -type f -mtime +7 ! -iname '.*'`, take the parent directory(of the found files), make a new folder with the `parent directory` name in a different directory and add a `_todaysDate` (`date '+%m%d&y`) and move the found files in there.

what would be best to do this? `while`? `for`? `do` loops? How would you go about doing that?

thanks in advance!

EDIT: To give you a file structure example

```
folder1
   - folder2
      -oldfile1

folder1a
   - folder2a
      -folder3a
        -oldfile2

----
In a new directory, a new folder would be created ( and that folder's name would be the parent folder of the old file, and tagged with a date (_040114) - this is where i get the format date '+%m%d%y) and the old files would then be moved in there. Example below -

- new_directory
  - folder2_date
    - oldfile1
  - folder3a_date
    - oldfile2
```

I hope this clarifies what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specification could really do with an example file-structure, as it leaves much open to interpretation. Which (of a number of common use-cases, each of which would get a different answer) are you wanting?

Here is something to get you started. I've made the assumptions that:

- you are running the script from /HERE/
- you want the archived files to land up in /THERE/
- you are running in a directory containing sub-directories (eg. /HERE/lie/old/files.txt)
- you want something like /THERE/lie_MMDDYY/old/files.txt

`find . -type f -mtime +7 -printf '%h\n' \
      | sort -u \
      | sed -e 's,^./,,' \
      | while read olddir
        do 
          moveto="/THERE/$(echo \"$olddir\" | cut -d/ -f1)_$(date +%m%d%y)/$(echo \"$olddir\" | cut -d/ -f2-)"
          echo mv "$olddir" "$moveto"
        done`

When ready to run it "in anger", remove the "echo". I had all of this one line, but split it out for readability.

I would recommend that you change the date format to use $(date -I), as the output will sort much more readily.

Comment: does the edit above give you more of an example? I think you've assumed everything pretty close. Does the edit above change your way of tackling this?

Comment: I'm going to award you with the answer.. even though there were some modifications, this did lead me to figure out my problem. Thanks @cameron-kerr!